# My DNS zone foo.com resolves the SOA but doesn't resolve the A record

Tags: domain-name-system, soa-record

named.conf.local (included in named.conf)

```
zone "foo.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/foo.com.hosts";
    };
```

DNS zone

```
$ttl 600

foo.com.    IN  SOA server.hostname. mail.server.hostname. (
            1369844282
            600
            600
            600
            600 )
foo.com.    IN  NS  server.hostname.

fake            A        99.99.99.99
```

`dig` test

```
dig fake.foo.com +trace
[...]
foo.com.             600     IN      SOA     server.hostname. mail.server.hostname. 1369844282 600 600 600 600
```

**Why `fake` is not resolved? What i'm missing?**

### Some more details

DNS for this server are managed from a domain panel on a hosting.

On that DNS panel i've set a subdomain as NS record pointing to the server.

Hosting DNS Panel Records

```
@           A   99.99.99.99     
www     A   99.99.99.99     
ftp     A   99.99.99.99         
beta    A   99.99.99.99
_domainkey  NS      99.99.99.99
```

So, when i talk about the `fake` record, i mean that `dig` can't resolve `fake._domainkey.foo.com` because, as already said, answer me with the SOA and not with the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issues was in the _domainkey NS record in the hosting DNS panel, because it didn't work properly.

i've added the records directly in the DNS hosting panel and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reloading bind after making those files?

I'm not sure what your OS is, but one of these should do the trick:

`$ rndc reload foo.com`

or

`killall -HUP named`

These will reload the config without taking the service down. Barring that, the nuclear option:

`service named restart`

or

`/etc/init.d/named restart`

Comment: yes, thank you.  I've already reloaded the zone. Now i've tried a bind9 restart (i'm on Ubuntu 12.04) but nothing, I keep to reach only the SOA

Comment: Have you verified that the zone is loading properly? Check the output of the commands `named-checkzone foo.com /var/lib/bind/foo.com.hosts` and `named-checkconf -z`, and check the name server's log file for errors on startup.

Comment: yes, everything seems regular https://gist.github.com/apelliciari/5676266 :(